# Why is long video taking long time before VideoJS player gets metadata to start playing?

Tags: html, ffmpeg, html5-video, video.js

Does anyone know why it is taking so long before the `loadedmetadata` event is fired for longer videos?

Here is an example: https://www.la1tv.co.uk/player/124/260

I can see in developer tools that the file is still downloading when the event is fired, so it's not like it's having to download the whole file, it's just having to get quite far though before the event is fired.

The ffmpeg command I am using to encode the video from java is:

```
RuntimeHelper.executeProgram(new String[] {config.getString("ffmpeg.location"), "-y", "-nostdin", "-timelimit", ""+config.getInt("ffmpeg.videoEncodeTimeLimit"), "-progress", ""+f.progressFile.getAbsolutePath(), "-i", source.getAbsolutePath(), "-vf", "scale=trunc(("+f.h+"*a)/2)*2:"+f.h, "-strict", "experimental", "-acodec", "aac", "-b:a", f.aBitrate+"k", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "48000", "-vcodec", "libx264", "-vprofile", "main", "-g", "48", "-b:v", f.vBitrate+"k", "-maxrate", f.vBitrate+"k", "-bufsize", f.vBitrate*2+"k", "-preset", "medium", "-crf", "16", "-vsync", "vfr", "-af", "aresample=async=1000", "-movflags", "+faststart", "-r", f.fr+"", "-f", "mp4", f.outputFile.getAbsolutePath()}, workingDir, null, null);
```

which can be found [here](https://github.com/LA1TV/Website-Upload-Processor/blob/177df3797b9ba9cbeee758102d181041051e4a9a/src/main/java/uk/co/la1tv/websiteUploadProcessor/fileTypes/VODVideoFileType.java#L137).

It has the `faststart` flag set and I thought this meant the metadata would be inserted right at the beginning of the file?

Could it be an issue with the encode settings?

Thanks!

Comment: Could be a metadata placement problem. The file is about 10 gb so if the browser need to seek/look it will take some time. Did you do a hex dump of the file to see if you are able to locate the metadata? I did start on something but it's a bit too big to download.. I would generally suggest splitting the file, f.ex. maybe it's better to split it per hour (it has 9.5), or at least at logic location. Even smaller segments, and then use a playlist feature to playback. This would also help with traffic "overload".

Comment: I did a buffer visualizer to see what the browser loaded. The first time in Firefox it loaded the complete 2/5 at the *end* before playing, but I was unable to reproduce this the next times so it could have been a glitch.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not really sure what I'm looking for. Does this look like it might be the meta data to you? This is the start of one of the videos on the site.

http://snag.gy/8k4wP.jpg

Comment: It seem to contain all needed data blocks/chunks. It could possibly be a server side problem too, if the server tries to push the whole file in one go (ie non-buffered, or the blocks are large) and the browser need to time-out on it (or cache limit kicks in). I would check the server config for this to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: The content is served using the Symphony library (through Laravel) in php (https://github.com/LA1TV/Website/blob/37d361be36da712cf2185e9e9413faeed5895008/app/serviceProviders/upload/UploadManager.php#L383) and it appears to be handling partial content requests correctly, as I can jump to various points in the video instantly and see new requeests being made in developer tools. Do you know if there's any tools I can use to get stats from the file coming from the server?

Comment: This may help: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler